# How can I get Visual Assist to parse Pro*C (*.pc) files?

Tags: c++, visual-assist

We have some applications that use Pro*C for database interactions.  I've gotten used to the features offered by Visual Assist, but I can't seem to get any of those features to work when editing Pro*C files, since Visual Assist doesn't seem to be parsing the files.  Even if I can get auto-completion to work, and only that, it would make life significantly easier when editing these files.  How can I do this?

I haven't found anything in the settings dialog for Visual Assist. If it matters, I'm using an old version (10.7.1929.0) since we haven't renewed our licenses.  If this is solved in newer versions, that would give us good reason to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Visual Assist recognize non-standard extensions via a tweak to the registry, as described is this Knowledge Base article:

http://support.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W328

Or follow these instructions:

For VS2013, add your extension to ExtSource in the following location in your registry. Remember to include the dot and terminating semicolon in the value:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Whole Tomato \ Visual Assist X \ VANet12 \

Replace VANet12 with the devstudio version for other IDEs you have--you should see multiple entries in the Visual Assist X branch if you do.

Press Rebuild on the Performance tab of the Visual Assist options dialog and restart your IDE(s).

Assuming you have Visual Studio 2010 or newer, add your extension to:

IDE | Tools | Options | Text Editor | File Extension | Microsoft Visual C++

IDE | Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | VC++ Project Settings | Extensions To Include

Build 1929 should suffice.

Comment: Please include the relevant information from the linked article in your answer. Linking to external resources is very helpful, but it's desired to include the information in the answer as well.

Comment: Just checking to make sure this works before accepting.  Thanks!